# Cannot link to WinApi in Qt Console application

Tags: windows, qt, winapi

I am trying to access some functions from WinApi in a Qt project with no success. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        char title[1024];
        HWND hwndHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
        GetWindowText(hwndHandle, (LPWSTR)title, 1023);

    return a.exec();
}
```

And these are the errors I get:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__GetWindowTextW@12 referenced in function _main
>
> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__GetForegroundWindow@0 referenced in function _main

is there any lib I should include in pro file to make this work?

Comment: You have to link against User32.lib to use these functions, I think.

Comment: it works. thank you. Add your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: A simple web search with the obvious keywords would have shown this as a dupe many times over. Don't neglect basic research when you get stuck.

Comment: @Mihai, there is already an answer, so it doesn't make sense adding the same twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordind to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) those functions in library User32. So you have to add

```
LIBS += -luser32
```

in pro file.